# reprepro use when multiple sources have the same codename

Tags: linux, apt

I'm investigating the use of reprepro to control what updates get propagated to our servers, and when.

The idea is to vet updates by Debian and Ubuntu, and only apply the ones we choose.  We want to do this by pointing /etc/apt/sources.list solely at reprepro, and to use a single location to do this, rather than using apt-whatever to pin on each machine separately.

The problem I'm facing is that some packages we use come from a PPA organized identically to the Ubuntu repos, with the same codenames; reprepro complains, for example, that there are two entries in conf/distributions with codename precise, one being Ubuntu, and one being the PPA.

How can I overcome this problem in reprepro?  Also, do I need to use some other software?

Answer (score 0):

You should create another reprepro repository next to the first one, containing only the debs from the PPA. This requires discipline from you and your coworkers. You'll have to add a second line in the sources.list file as well.

I think you're hitting the limits of the software. You should have a look at [Aptly](http://www.aptly.info) which looks pretty nice and has quite advanced features.